# error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of unique_ptr with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr, auto

I have two template declarations as follows:

```
template < typename T >
      class node {
        public:
          ...
        const unique_ptr < node < T >> & getParent();
        ...
        private:
          ...
        unique_ptr < node < T >> & P; //for parent node
        ...
      };

    template < typename T1, typename T2 >
      class tree {
        public:
          tree(int, T2 & );
        ...
        void travPreord();
        ...
        private:
          ...
      };
```

Within the definition of the public method

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> tree<T1,T2>::travPreord()
```

I have the following code:

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 > 
    void tree < T1, T2 > ::travPreord() {

      //lambda definition

      function < void(unique_ptr < node < T1 >> & ) > prntNode = [ & ]
      (unique_ptr < node < T1 >> & pN) {

        ...

        if(auto rPN = pN - > getParent()) {

          ...

        }

      };

    }
```

For the assignment inside the if statement condition above, I get the following error from the compiler (g++ 4.2.1):

> error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
>   'std::__1::unique_ptr >,
>   std::__1::default_delete > > >'
>   if(auto rPN = pN->getParent()){

The arguments to the template instantiation highlighted in the error are supplied from the main():

```
int main() {

      vector < string > v;

      ...

      tree < string, vector < string >> T(v.size(), v);

      T.travPreord();

      ...

      return 0;

    }
```

I wrote the if statement condition under question on the following assumptions:

1. It is possible to assign a unique_ptr to a reference.
2. The auto keyword should deduce the type of the lvalue expression `rPN` to be the type of the rvalue expression `pN->getParent()`, which returns a type `unique_ptr<node<T>>&.`

So I am not sure about the source of this error.

Could anyone point to the same?

Comment: If I'm reading [the type deduction rules for templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) (which `auto` uses) correctly, the original type, `P`, has referenceness stripped when determining the deduced type, `A` (see item #3 after "Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to P and A are made:", which states "If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for deduction."). Basically, `auto` means value type unless you explicitly make it `auto&&` or `auto&`. Using `const auto&` (and maybe `auto&&`; my C++ is rusty) should work.

Comment: code snippets with lots of `...` are not good to describe a good problem to be StackOverflow solved.  Please, illustrate your example with a complete, verifiable and reproducible code.  Also, in the question, you refer to a deleted copy constructor, thing that cannot happen, you can delete an instance, or several, but never the copy constructor.... vage questions demand vague responses.... please, correct that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. The auto keyword should deduce the type of the lvalue expression `rPN` to be the type of the rvalue expression `pN->getParent()`, which returns a type `unique_ptr<node<T>>&`.

No, the type will be `unique_ptr<node<T>>`.

[Auto type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#auto_type_deduction) applies same rules as template argument deduction; the reference part of the expression (i.e. `pN->getParent()`) is ignored, after that the `const` part is ignored too. So the result type is `unique_ptr<node<T>>`.

You need to specify that it's should be a reference explicitly, e.g.

```
auto& rPN = pN - > getParent() // rPN is of type const unique_ptr<node<T>>&
```

> 1. It is possible to assign a unique_ptr to a reference.

Of course yes. The problem is that `rPN` is not a reference.